# How to draw Smooth straight line by using UIBezierPath?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibezierpath

I want to be able to draw straight lines on my iPad screen using an `UIBezierPath`. How would I go about this?

What I want to do is something like this: I double tap on the screen to define the start point. Once my finger is above the screen the straight line would move with my finger (this should happen to figure out where I should put my next finger so that it will create a straight line). Then, if I double tap on screen again the end point is defined.

Further, a new line should begin if I double tap on the end point.

Are there any resources available that I can use for guidance?

Comment: It is the norm to put some kind of explanation when down-voting.

Comment: @raaz You aren't going to be able to track the user's finger once it stops touching the glass. Well, unless you implement some Minority Report-esque magic with the camera, but I think that is hardly worth the monumental effort. The rest is easily achievable: just funnel the `UITouch` information into @StuDev's answer (the points of the `UIBezierPath`).

Answer (score 8):

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:startOfLine];
[path addLineToPoint:endOfLine];
[path stroke];
```

[UIBezierPath Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)

**EDIT**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Create an array to store line points
    self.linePoints = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Create double tap gesture recognizer
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) {

        CGPoint touchPoint = [sender locationInView:sender.view];

        // If touch is within range of previous start/end points, use that point.
        for (NSValue *pointValue in linePoints) {
            CGPoint linePoint = [pointValue CGPointValue];
            CGFloat distanceFromTouch = sqrtf(powf((touchPoint.x - linePoint.x), 2) + powf((touchPoint.y - linePoint.y), 2));
            if (distanceFromTouch < MAX_TOUCH_DISTANCE) {    // Say, MAX_TOUCH_DISTANCE = 20.0f, for example...
                touchPoint = linePoint;
            }
        }

        // Draw the line:
        // If no start point yet specified...
        if (!currentPath) {
            currentPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
            [currentPath moveToPoint:touchPoint];
        }

        // If start point already specified...
        else { 
            [currentPath addLineToPoint:touchPoint];
            [currentPath stroke];
            currentPath = nil;
        }

        // Hold onto this point
        [linePoints addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:touchPoint]];
    }
}
```

I'm not writing any Minority Report-esque camera magic code without monetary compensation.

Comment: @studdev,i have added some further explanation what i want to do